# Session variables won't be remembered to the next page

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to build a word guessing game, where people input their name, and they are given 5 tries to guess a game (The first letter is free).

I had the game working all fine and dandy, but I decided to add a ''starting'' page, where people can enter their names, and where the random word is already pre-chosen for the actual game page. (It rand's a word from a 20-word array)

But now for some reason, everytime I have people enter the game, it immediately skips past the game screen and immediately jumps to the win-screen... It's supposed to show the name and the winning word on said screen, but it doesn't show either of them, it's just blank.

So i'm assuming that for some reason, the two variables aren't being remembered after you enter the name, as such the game comparing null to null and the game being ''won''...

Obviously, this shouldn't happen. A word should be picked out of the array, and put in a session_variable. Same goes with the name that you input into the form.

Seeing as it's a three-page PHP script, I will put links to Hastebin rather than post snippets here. Sorry for that in advance, but I think it'll work better...

**Start Screen:** http://hastebin.com/orisazubis.xml

**Game Screen:** http://hastebin.com/akuzekawil.php

Comment: so your code is in one php file?

Comment: No, all three pages are in their own PHP files. The links to and from each-other work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look through all of that but why not try `$_SESSION` since that's what PHP populates?  You do know that PHP variables are case sensitive right?

Comment: So you're saying that you not only need to write the variable names case sensitive, but also $_SESSION?

I never thought of that, and after trying, it actually works! Thanks dude, I learned something new and I feel foolish :)

Comment: Yes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php and http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

replace `$session` and `$_session` to `$_SESSION` everywhere

in your:

http://hastebin.com/orisazubis.xml
change:

```
if($random == null) {
        $session = $woorden[rand(0,19)];
}
```

to

```
if($random == null) {
        $_SESSION['random'] = $woorden[rand(0,19)];
}
```

and finally in file
http://hastebin.com/akuzekawil.php

change :

```
$random = $_session['random'];
```

to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['random'])) {
$random = $_SESSION['random'];
}else{
$random=null;
}
```

check here also:

```
$_session['naam'] = $_POST['naam'];
```

change to:

```
   if (isset($_POST['naam']) && !empty($_POST['naam']){
        $_SESSION['naam'] = $_POST['naam'];
} else {
       $_SESSION['naam'] = null;
}
```

update line:

```
if($random == $testen){
```

to

```
if(!empty($testen) && $random == $testen){
```

if I got right your logic

Comment: Sadly enough, it made no discernable difference. It still skips right past my game page and to the win page.

Comment: some more updates :-) suggestion: just do debug more often. there are so many things to fix.